# Connect order number on Wix module page from a stripe order link

Tags: stripe-payments, velo

I am trying to create an ordering process that starts from the product page, than a button links to a stripe checkout link and from there I would like (when the user completes the checkout) to show a link that has a custom parameter or a query argument that is referring to the order number that will be passed/retrieved (when the user clicks) to the Wix page on a custom label that shows the order number.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Checkout Session, you can pass a `success_url` where your customer will be redirected after a successful payment. You control that URL so you can put what you need in it to identify the customer when they come back.

Separately, you can use `metadata` to store information such as the Wix order number that you want to map them with.

After a successful payment, your customer is redirected back to your Wix page where you will be able to write code to retrieve the Session via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) and find the corresponding Wix order number.